# Failed HDD with no hope? Please help

Tags: hard-drive

I have a 1TB HDD that suddenly won't open. Mac asks to initialize it but when I do, nothing happens.
Tried formatting it, with no success.
Some pictures of the issue:
[image: Mac message]
Mac message
[image: Disk Utility]
[image: Disk List]
[image: Disk Drill]
[image: The disk is turning on but the blinking light won't.]
The disk is turning on but the blinking light won't.
Can anything be done?

Comment: If you need the data, send it to a data recovery specialist. But, (if my math is any good & it rarely is ;) judging from Disk Drill's analysis, you have something like 200MB of bad sectors, which would really tell me you have a *major* fail.

Comment: If I’m not mistaken, the Volume header is located at the very beginning of the drive, the alternate at the very end and journaling somewhere in the middle.  This seems to be where all of your bad blocks are located.   Try to do a low level rescue, and if successful, throw that drive into the bin; it can’t be trusted any more.

Comment: Do you actually need to recover anything from the drive? Normally, you wouldn't initialize or format a drive with data that you wanted to keep, as that would erase it all.

Comment: @Tetsujin OP said he tried to format it, so apparently there's no necessary data on it.

Comment: @MarcWilson - there's a common misconception along the lines of 'if only I can initialise it, it will make it easier to get my data back' which one must always make allowances for in any question like this.

Comment: @Allan - How can the low level procedure be done?

Comment: @benwiggy - I do need the data. I was hoping I cloud Initialize/format it and then use DiskDrill to recover it.

Comment: Paid DiskDrill (maybe the Pro version) does sector by sector recovery

Comment: @grounded_ How old is your backup of this data?

Comment: @MarcWilson - There is no backup of this data :(

Comment: In which case, my opening comment is still the most salient - *"If you need the data, send it to a data recovery specialist."* If those bad sector reports are anything like accurate, I'd think they will have to either disassemble the platters completely, or replace the heads. As the warning often goes "no user serviceable parts inside".